# Install QGIS3 (QGIS-dev) on MacOSX

Tags: mac, qgis-3

As it mentioned on [the official doc](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#qgis-macos-testing)
we can download a nightly build for QGIS-dev-2.99.

I did, but the version is actually outdated `QGIS_2-99-0_2016-09-20_cd1d44b.dmg` it's the 2.15 dev version instead of the 3.0.

How can I get and install the QGIS3 on MacOSX 10.11.6 El Capitan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to do right now is using [`homebrew`](https://brew.sh/) and the [`qgis/qgisdev`](https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev) tap or wait for the official release.

Comment: thanks I will try. It could be nicer if you give the entire command to get the last qgisdev on Mac by hombrew.

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup If you have homebrew installed (otherwise go ahead and install it), just do a `brew install qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev`

Comment: please, edit your answer. we also need xcode.app to get it work. maybe if you can tell where to find a documentation to compile qgis on mac. thanks

Comment: I get an error with QT5-webkit : `Installing qgis3-dev from qgis/qgisdev
qt5-webkit: Must be built with brew install --no-sandbox ..., or install steps will fail.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.` what should I do ?

Comment: with `brew install --no-sandbox qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev`  it's  compiling.

Comment: Hopefully it compiles successfully! Seems that the error that you had depends on the MacOS version that you are currently running. I did not have that issue, but hopefully it will help anyone having it!

Comment: i did a homebrew-install in november without any serious problems. troubles began as soon as i've tried to update this install. so finally i decided to do a clean reinstall of anything. everything worked fine until the reinstall of qgis "brew install qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev"  
some warnigs ... "Warning: Calling 'depends_on :python3' is deprecated!
Use 'depends_on "python3"' instead.  some errors:   
"Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/science/matplotlib" (dependency of qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev). ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula ...

Comment: ... Warning: homebrew/science is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/science)" fetch --unshallow
Error: No previously deleted formula found.  install didn't finish at all !

Comment: Same error for me: `Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/science/matplotlib" (dependency of qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev)
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
homebrew/science/matplotlib was deleted from homebrew/science in commit 224eed91:
  Deprecate Homebrew/homebrew-science (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/6616)`

More discussion here: https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/issues/50

Comment: This is the closest I've come:

`brew install --no-sandbox https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smellman/homebrew-qgisdev/qgis-build-test-matplotlib/Formula/qgis3-dev.rb`

This branch has a fix for the deprecation of matplotlib, including it as a python package. I had to run the command twice but still errored: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: ... that's annoying. because there have been some complaining messages from the developer side, indicating that there is a lack of mac-testing. but on trying to invest into pre release testig you are faced with that kind of troubles. beeing a user this is nothing i am able (and willing) to handle ...  the dakota-link (which is the only alternative reference i have found) is dead at least for the last 2 years and the guys from nextgis have announced a master-release some months ago - but nothing happend since then ... anyone any ideas ???

Comment: @roberttuw this is sadly how QGIS has been for awhile on mac. I have always had issues with finding the latest release while that release has been out for a while on Windows/Linux. I would recommend trying to build QGIS from source yourself, but that is not an easy task either.
I would be open to discuss doing this and hosting the new releases for the sake of having it working for everyone on mac.

Comment: @tgirgin - i'm even more interested right now. since 1) didn't find a working version of the homebrew-install for the last weeks - same error message every time. 2) qgis3 is already released - but not for mac. so if you are interested i would really realy appreciate that, but i'm afraid, i am no help at all concerning the release building and hosting process !

Comment: @roberttuw I am definitely thinking of starting the process since it does not seem that the QGIS devs have the resources to do so. I will try to do so tonight. I am not promising anything since I have never build QGIS from source but I will post the package here if I successfully build it!

Comment: coool !  let's hope  and thx for the effort !!!!

Comment: Still not working for me via homebrew -- even with trying all the hacks :( If anyone has ideas or needs help testing other processes happy to help!

Comment: You'll have to work on the homebrew formula yourself or hope that someone else does it. I do not think it is currently working.
I have made some good progress on the QGIS 3.0 build for Mac, but I have been slowed down by other projects/work. Will keep this updated if I successfully have a build that I can share!

Answer (score 2):

"Official" release is now out http://kyngchaos.com/software/qgis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experiment with other python modules on Mac, other than those comes with [KyngChaos](http://kyngchaos.com/software/qgis.) then try [Boundless QGIS](https://boundlessgeo.com/qgis/). I have tried and tested it on Mac.